# Chicago Blackhawks logo Lego building instructions

Tags: design

Can anyone make some building instructions for the Chicago Blackhawks logo that's made out of LEGO bricks? I'm trying to find so I can build it for my sick brother.

Comment: is [this](http://www.cbssports.com/nhl/eye-on-hockey/22515098/photo-blackhawks-logo-made-entirely-out-of-legos) what you are talking about?

Comment: I didn't know LEGO came in that sort of orange colour.

Comment: Andrew Johnson, a LEGO master model builder created that replica of the Blackhawks logo. The logo measures 2 feet by 3 feet and weighs 20 pounds. It took Johnson about 16 hours to build it, comprised of 756 LEGO. Someone has an [eBay listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Custom-LEGO-Blackhawks-Logo-INSTRUCTIONS-ONLY-2-000-Piece-Model-/221506335932?hash=item3392ce74bc:g:y8cAAOSwhglTwgil) for instructions on building a version as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest you're likely to get, I made it myself. Basically, LEGO art is a form of pixel art. The 2x2 brick is the best brick for this purpose, but often you can use blocks of other length to make the build faster, and more sound. All I did here was take a basic Blackhawks logo, apply a pixelation filter, and then hand-integrate all the pixels into the basic LEGO pallet. I also hand-placed studs for reference, and used a non-LEGO color for the background, and a shadow, to remove confusion. Then I squished all the pixels down to LEGO proportions.

You will be using a lot of yellow, 2 light grey, 4 dark grey, a good bit of black, some green, some orange, and a little bit of white and blue.

[image: Made with Paint.net]